# JS: Adding and removing elements in nested array, which represents table data

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

There is an nested array, which should represent some table data:

```
var array = [ 
    [ "r1c1", "r1c2", "r1c3" ], 
    [ "r2c1", "r2c2", "r2c3" ],
    [ "r3c1", "r3c2", "r3c3" ] 
]
```

Now I need to manipulate the array structure to

1. Add new column or row (for example new column between first and second)
2. Remove a specific row or column

Removing a row should be quite simple

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

To remove an column I would think I have to iterate throught the array:

```
array.forEach(row => {
    row.splice(index, 1);
});
```

But I think there is missing something here.

The main problem for me is adding a row or column: To add a new row I could use `array.push(["new", "new", "new"])` or `array.unshift(["new", "new", "new"])`, but how should I add a row in between?

**Expected results**

*Adding row* with index = 1 should result in:

```
array = [ 
    [ "r1c1", "r1c2", "r1c3" ], 
    ["new", "new", "new"],
    [ "r2c1", "r2c2", "r2c3" ],
    [ "r3c1", "r3c2", "r3c3" ] 
]
```

*Adding column* with index = 1 should result in:

```
array = [ 
    [ "r1c1", "new", "r1c2", "r1c3" ], 
    [ "r2c1", "new", "r2c2", "r2c3" ],
    [ "r3c1", "new", "r3c2", "r3c3" ] 
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function:

```
var arr = [ "r1c1", "r1c2", "r1c3" ];
// delete 0 elements and then add "new" element at 1 position
arr.splice(1, 0, "new");
console.log(arr); [ "r1c1", "new", "r1c2", "r1c3" ];
```

So it could look like:

```
var array = [
    [ "r1c1", "r1c2", "r1c3" ],
    [ "r2c1", "r2c2", "r2c3" ],
    [ "r3c1", "r3c2", "r3c3" ]
];

// adding column
array.forEach(arr => arr.splice(1, 0, "new"));

// adding row
array.splice(1, 0, ["new", "new", "new"])
```

Comment: So to keep it general `1` should be a variable (`index`) and `0` is `index-1`?

Comment: @user3142695 no, `1` should be `index`, and `0` should be `0` (since you don't want to delete any element)

Answer (score 0):

You could create one function for all of operations.

1. `n` is position where to insert or delete
2. `col_row` is `column` or `row`.
3. `change` can be `add` or `delete`.
4. `insert` is optional parameter if you are adding new row or column.

```js
var array = [
  ["r1c1", "r1c2", "r1c3"],
  ["r2c1", "r2c2", "r2c3"],
  ["r3c1", "r3c2", "r3c3"]
];

function addColumn(n, col_row, change, insert = 'new') {
  if (col_row == 'column') {
    array.forEach(function(e, i) {
      if (change == 'add') {
        e.splice(n, 0, insert);
      } else if (change == 'delete') {
        e.splice(n, 1);
      }
    })
  } else {
    if (change == 'add') array.splice(n, 0, insert);
    if (change == 'delete') array.splice(n, 1);
  }

  console.log(array)
}

addColumn(1, 'column', 'add', 'Lorem ipsum')
addColumn(2, 'column', 'delete')
addColumn(2, 'row', 'add', Array(3).fill('new'))
```